# Modifying Group Header to include children count Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid created in javascript. I have a defalut grouping, then the user can select other groupings. Ineed help with a couple things:

1.I would like to make a custom group header so it includes a count of the children rows.

2. On mouseover of the Group Header I need to change the related marker on a Google Maps instance. (The group contains the lat and long of the client.

   ```
   function loadGrid(dataItem) {
       $("#grid").kendoGrid({
           dataSource: {
               dataType: "json",
               transport: {
                   read: {
                       url: serviceUrl",
                       dataType: "json",
                   },
               },
               schema: {
                   data: "result.results",
               },
               group: {
                   field: "siteName", field: "siteName",
               },
           },
           dataBound: onDataBound,
           pageSize: 20,
           height: 550,
           filterable: true,
           groupable: true,
           sortable: true,
           pageable: true,
           collapse: true,
           columns: [
               {
                   field: "dirId",
                   title: "Dir Id",
                   hidden: true
               },
               {
                   field: "dirName",
                   Title: "Dir Name",
                   hidden: true
               },
               {
                   field: "siteId",
                   title: "Site Id",
                   hidden: true
               },
               {
                   field: "siteName",
                   title: "Site Name",
                   //hidden: true
               },
               {
                   field: "appTypeRefId",
                   title: "App Type Ref Id",
                   hidden: true
               },
               {
                   field: "appInstName",
                   title: "App Instance Name",
               },
               {
                   field: "appTypeName",
                   title: "App Type",
               },

               {
                   field: "unitId",
                   title: "Unit Id",
                   hidden: true
               },
               {
                   field: "unitName",
                   title: "Unit Name"
               },
               {
                   field: "controlSystemId",
                   title: "Control System Id",
                   hidden: true
               },
               {
                   field: "controlSystemName",
                   title: "Control System Name"
               },
               {
                   field: "longitude",
                   title: "Longitude",
                   hidden: true
               },
               {
                   field: "latitude",
                   title: "Latitude",
                   hidden: true
               },

           ],
       })
   }
   ```

Thanks a ton!
Ron